# WM_PAINT message and EnumDisplayMonitors

Tags: c++, winapi, multiple-monitors, gdi

I'm trying to adapt a screensaver written in C++ with WinAPIs to work for multiple monitors. I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7831/Dual-Multiple-Monitor-Support-in-Win32) that suggests to rewrite this basic WM_PAINT handler:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps = {0};
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps );

    DoDrawing(hdc, ps.rcPaint);

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}
break;

void DoDrawing(HDC hDC, RECT rcDraw)
{
    //Do actual drawing in 'hDC'
}
```

Into something like this to incorporate drawing for multiple screens:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps = {0};
    HDC hdcE = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps );

    EnumDisplayMonitors(hdcE,NULL, MyPaintEnumProc, 0);

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}
break;

BOOL CALLBACK MyPaintEnumProc(
      HMONITOR hMonitor,  // handle to display monitor
      HDC hdc1,     // handle to monitor DC
      LPRECT lprcMonitor, // monitor intersection rectangle
      LPARAM data       // data
      )
{
    RECT rc = *lprcMonitor;
    // you have the rect which has coordinates of the monitor

    DoDrawing(hdc1, rc);

    // Draw here now
    return 1;
}
```

But the question I have is what about special optimization/clipping that BeginPaint() sets up in the DC after processing WM_PAINT message? With this approach it will be lost. Any idea how to preserve it across the EnumDisplayMonitors() call?

Comment: What makes you think it's being lost? `EnumDisplayMonitors` is blocking so `EndPaint()` won't be called until it's finished. Oh, and what are you actually trying to paint on? a single window for the desktop, one for each monitor or some other window? You may have more luck by enumerating once on startup.

Comment: I'm trying to paint specifically for each monitor. Otherwise the DC is spread/stretched across all the monitors.

Comment: Your enumeration tells you which monitor is being passed to `DoDrawing()`, so what is the actual problem you are having drawing different things to different monitors? If you read the documentation more carefully, it shows you how to use `EnumDisplayMonitors()` for drawing individual monitors.

Comment: OK, let's assume that this code is used on a system with a single monitor. In that case BeginPaint will prepare the DC to clip out all unnecessary regions. If I keep the code the way it is (posted above) that clipping region will not be used because EnumDisplayMonitors will return a new DC. That's what I mean. It will work fine, it just won't be as efficient...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually described in the MSDN docs for [EnumDisplayMonitors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610(v=vs.85).aspx). When you pass an HDC parameter to EnumDisplayMonitors, then the DC it passes to your callback function is a subset of the DC that you originally passed in with these changes:

- The clip has been further reduced to only cover the intersection of the original clip with the monitor's clip rectangle.
- The color format of the DC is for the specific monitor rather than for the "primary" monitor of the window.

Note that in modern Windows (at least since Win8), you will never really see different color formats in practice for Window DCs since GDI always runs with 32-bit color.

Comment: Hey, it didn't take 5 yrs to get a reply :)

Comment: Haha, better late than never?